# How to get end time using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/akuber/1/edit) Here in jsbin demo i m getting start time but i dnt know any idea how to get end time.
 how should i go further to get end time.
**i dont want to change html.** 
i have to get end time using  present html.
i m trying since last three days.

```
$("#btnAllot").click(function ()
            { var calculateStartMins = $('td.csstd:first');var calculateStartHrs = calculateStartMins.parent().prevAll().andSelf().find('td:first-child').filter(function(){return $.trim($(this).text()) !== '';}).last();
                    var fromTime = calculateStartHrs.text().trim() + calculateStartMins.text().trim();
                    var fromTimeAMPM = fromTime.substring(5, 7);
                    var fromTimeHour = fromTime.trim().substring(0, 2);
                    var fromTimeMinute = fromTime.substring(7, 10);
                    var hidFromTime = fromTimeHour.trim() +":"+ fromTimeMinute.trim();alert("Start Time is "+hidFromTime.trim()); 
             var endTime = $('td.csstd:last').parent().next().andSelf().find('td:first-child').
                filter(function ()
                {return $.trim($(this).text()) !== '';
               }).last();alert("End Time is "+endTime);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking way too complicated, I guess... See if this works for you:

```
$("#btnAllot").click(function(){
    var begin = $("td.csstd:first"), end = $("td.csstd:last"),
        beginHour, endHour, endMinute, currentHour, beginTime, endTime;
    $("tr.csstablelisttd").each(function(){
        var minuteTd = $(this).find("td").eq(1),
            t = $(this).find("td:first").text().trim();
        (t.length) && (currentHour = t);
        (minuteTd.filter(begin).length > 0) && (beginHour = currentHour);
        (minuteTd.filter(end).length > 0)   && (endHour   = currentHour);
    });

    endHour = endHour.replace(/00/, "").split(":");
    endHour[0] = Number(endHour[0]);
    endMinute = (Number(end.text().trim())+15) % 60;
    if (endMinute == 0) {
        endHour[0] = (endHour[0] + 1) % 12;
        if (endHour[0] == 0) {
            endHour[0] = 12;
            endHour[1] = endHour[1] == "AM" ? "PM" : "AM";
        }
    }
    (endHour[0] < 10) && (endHour[0] = "0"+endHour[0]);
    (endMinute < 10) && (endMinute = "0"+endMinute);

    beginTime = beginHour.replace(/00/, begin.text().trim()); 
    endTime   = endHour[0] + ":" + endMinute + endHour[1];

    alert("Start time is "+beginTime);
    alert("End time is "+endTime);
});
```

[**DEMO** (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Aletheios/SeXhH/1/)

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/eheroy/1/edit)

Comment: Aletheios each time slot is 15 minute.if u select 02:00 pm only one slot then start time be  02:00 pm and end time be  02:15 pm..like that others

Comment: i m unable to see Html can u pls post ur answer in jsbin

Comment: Ok, I see. This makes it a bit more complicated... I've updated my answer, see above. Besides, I used exactly your HTML structure because you said you didn't want to change the HTML.